# How to remap my Kinesis Freestyle 2 PC keyboard to Mac Layout

Tags: mac, keyboard

I want to remap my *Kinesis Freestyle 2* PC keyboard to Mac.

I can do most of it by swapping the modifier keys within the keyboard preferences, however I want to switch the right `CTRL` key to be an option key like in a default Mac keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download Karabiner (formerly known as KeyRemap4MacBook).  https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/
2. See this article on how to create a new 'Profile' and make open/edit 'private.xml'. http://www.keychatter.com/2014/08/04/how-to-remap-keys-in-osx-using-keyremap4macbook-now-karabiner/
3. Use this to remap the left hotkeys (only COPY, CUT, PASTE, UNDO) from PC hotkeys to Mac hotkey.

Copy/Paste this into your own 'private.xml' file, then ReloadXML, and check the boxes next to the new scripts shown in the 'remapping' section of 'Change Key' tab.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
  <name>COPY - Change Control-C to Command-C</name>
    <identifier>private.controlC_commandC</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ 
      KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, 
      KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
  <name>CUT - Change Control-X to Command-X</name>
    <identifier>private.controlX_commandX</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ 
      KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, 
      KeyCode::X, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
  <name>PASTE - Change Control-V to Command-V</name>
    <identifier>private.controlV_commandV</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ 
      KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, 
      KeyCode::V, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
  <name>UNDO - Change Control-Z to Command-Z</name>
    <identifier>private.controlZ_commandZ</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ 
      KeyCode::Z, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, 
      KeyCode::Z, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Does it work? I am planning to buy for pc and also want to use for Mac! Really appreciate if anyone who has done this setting and working for them can comment? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install KeyRemap4MacBook and save a file like this as `~/Library/Application Support/KeyRemap4MacBook/private.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>custom</name>
    <identifier>custom</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_R, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Then open the KeyRemap4MacBook application, press the ReloadXML button, and enable the setting.

See https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en or http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html for more information.